# Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, httpclient

I am trying to get a list of places from Google Map API and I get the following error.

The error is thrown when executing the HttpResponse.

paramurl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?&location=[LAT],[LNG]&types=movie_theater&radius=5000&sensor=true&key=[API_KEY]"

I have corrected the url above and the error is now changed I have posted it below this code snippet. [I removed the '&' from ...json?&location...]. Thanks @323go.

```
   try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(paramurl));
        int status = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (status == 200) {

            result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    **

}
```

Here the log:

```
10-22 17:00:02.338  24247-24247/com.mussie.android.blocspot.blocspot E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /51929ae149631b821866d0f99feccad0c41a8113: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-22 17:00:02.338  24247-24247/com.mussie.android.blocspot.blocspot D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-22 17:00:02.348  24247-24247/com.mussie.android.blocspot.blocspot E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mussie.android.blocspot.blocspot, PID: 24247
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.google.j.a.cl.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.cs.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.cr.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ac.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ae.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.dw.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.l.onTransact(SourceFile:167)
            at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.addMarker(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(Unknown Source)
            at com.mussie.android.blocspot.blocspot.MapsActivity$GetPOIs.onPostExecute(MapsActivity.java:435)
            at com.mussie.android.blocspot.blocspot.MapsActivity$GetPOIs.onPostExecute(MapsActivity.java:380)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

**

Comment: The paramurl is the URL sent to get the result in json format. I have checked the url in a browser and I get the desired data in json format.

Comment: What's the *content* of paramurl?

Comment: @Duke, thank you for adding the param url. Could you log it (and sanitize it), just to be sure it's correct? Also the `json?&location` looks incorrect. Drop the `&` and try it again.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue myself after going through each line of code that returned a json result.

1. I handled all the methods to check if there is a record returned by the server (In this case the Google Map API)
2. I was requesting all kinds of data for the given location (Malls, Bus Stations, Restaurants etc.) at the same time. Since my code is not optimized, problem was popping up everywhere.
3. The third and last thing I did was to clean up the manifest file (And make sure I put all the permissions in place).

Comment: nice, now set this as your answer please (check mark).